# How to combineLatest only when a particular Observable has changed

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am very new to RxSwift and trying to do the following:

My application needs to enable selection of "Elements" where the selection mode can be `single` selection (a new selection replaces an old selection) or `multiple`, where a selection is added to any old selection.

In `single` mode, if the new selection is the old selection, then my selection results must become empty (toggles the selection by selecting the same element).

In `multiple` mode, if the new selection is part of the old selection, the newly selected element is removed from the current selection.

I have three existing subjects: `selectionModeSubject` is a `BehaviorSubject` containing the `single` or `multiple` enumeration. `selectSubject` represents the new selection requested by the user, it is a `PublishSubject`. Finally, `currentSelectionSubject`, a `BehaviorSubject` containing the current Set of elements that are selected.

I'm trying to have `currentSelectionSubject` containing the resulting selection after `selectSubject` fires.

Here is what I have:

```
Observable
        .combineLatest(selectionModeSubject, selectSubject, currentSelectionSubject) { (mode, newSelection, currentSelection) -> Set<Element> in
            switch mode {
            case .single:
                if currentSelection.contains(newSelection) {
                    return Set([newSelection])
                } else {
                    return Set<Element>()
                }
            case .multiple:
                if currentSelection.contains(newSelection) {
                    return currentSelection.filter({ (element) -> Bool in
                        return element != newSelection
                    })
                } else {
                    return currentSelection.union(Set([newSelection]))
                }
            }
        }
        .bind(to: currentSelectionSubject)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The problem, amplified by my newbie RxSwift status, is that this observation code potentially fires whenever the `selectionModeSubject` or `currentSelectionSubject` fire. I would only want this to fire if `selectSubject` is changed.

I have tried to insert a `.distinctUntilChanged()` on the `selectSubject` but I cannot seem to come to grasp with it.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`withLatestFrom`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/65efb404c80fe1b23108c8fbb57d05b615e21c93/RxSwift/Observables/WithLatestFrom.swift#L20) is the way to go.

```
selectSubject.withLatestFrom(
  Observable
    .combineLatest(selectionModeSubject, currentSelectionSubject)) { newSelection, pair in
  let (mode, currentSelection) = pair

  return (mode, newSelection, currentSelection)
}.map { (mode, newSelection, currentSelection) -> Set<Element> in
  switch mode {
  case .single:
    if currentSelection.contains(newSelection) {
      return Set([newSelection])
    } else {
      return Set<Element>()
    }
    case .multiple:
      if currentSelection.contains(newSelection) {
        return currentSelection.filter({ (element) -> Bool in
          return element != newSelection
        })
      } else {
        return currentSelection.union(Set([newSelection]))
      }
    }
  }
  .bind(to: currentSelectionSubject)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```